# why jQuery code in dream weaver doesn't work in chrome?

Tags: jquery

I write this code in my dream weaver and run it but when run it show me this console :

```
75px 
75px 
61px 
73px
70px
```

my problem here !!! when I run this code in console chrome show it :

```
72px
71px
58px
70px
60px
```

this is my code :

```
<script>


                $(function(){
                for(var i=0 ; i < $('#in-form ul li').length ; i++)
                {
                    var wid = $('#in-form ul li label span').eq(i).css('width');
                    console.log(wid);
                    //$('#in-form ul li label input').eq(i).css('right',wid);
                }

                });

</script>
```

Comment: Apparently Chrome renders the HTML a bit differently. I wouldn't expect Dreamweaver to have a very good HTML renderer.

Comment: Like Felix said, don't expect Dreamweaver to render HTML as it should, check on all major browsers the rendered HTML if it is consistent across them. Usually, IDE for developing UI interface in js/html is completly useless. A simple text editor (e.g notepad++) is better IMO.

Comment: Agree with both the above. Dreamweaver is not a very good editor. Specifically because of the drag and drop components which, ultimately, do not write very good HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$(function(){
    $('#in-form ul li').each(function(){
        wid = $(this).find('label span').width()
        console.log(wid);
    })
});
```

Comment: I do this but when write this code is DW and run with chrome show top first part and when I write this code in console chrome show me second part of top

Comment: Impossible to help you with so little stuff.